# Animation not working android

Tags: android, android-animation, splash-screen

I am trying to use animation in the splashscreen. First time when the user opens the app the splash screen is called and after the db gets loaded first activity is called.

While db gets loaded the beow code is used for the animation. But it is not working.
Can anyone help me in this?

In the splash screen i have given the below code

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.app_icon);   
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0,200,0, 0);
animation.setDuration(75000);
animation.setRepeatCount(5);
animation.setRepeatMode(2);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
img_animation.startAnimation(animation);
```

and this is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#BDB76B"
tools:context=".Animation"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I see you have the animation duration set to 75,000 mils. That's 1 minute, 15 seconds. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: yes, that is wat I intend to do..

Answer (score 0):

`TranslateAnimation` expects a `float` value, not an `int`.

Try `TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f , 200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);`

Comment: Thanks Jrad.. I tried by changing to wat u have mentioned. But its still d same. No movement of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works, albeit very very slowly with that time, but it works. Are you loading the DB in using the main UI thread or its own separate thread? That could be hogging the cpu and preventing your animation from running.

Comment: Thanks meme.. I am using separate thread for loading db. Any other way  to make the animation work perfectly ?

Comment: I think I need to see more code then, as just using the code above works. Anything else that might be impacting it?